# What are the dimensions of a and b in van der Waal's real gas formula?

Tags: gas-laws

In the van der Waal's formula for real gases $\left( p+\frac{a}{V^2}\right)(V-b)=nRT$, what are the dimensions of $a$ and $b$?

I learnt that $a$ is related to the average force of attraction between the molecules and $b$ is related to the total volume of the molecules, but I fail to understand their dimensions.

Comment: There seem to be a few ways to write this formula - but this document http://www.roanestate.edu/faculty/chemistry/chemistryslideshows/vanderWaal/VDW.pdf may be of help.

Comment: Is there a reason why your [other question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7579/1573) couldn't be edited to include both the real and ideal gas laws?  It would make the question and answer easier to find for future visitors.

Answer (score 8):

Part of your confusion is in the formula you have written.  According to the Tanner's General Chemistry webpage [The van der Waals Equation](http://www.tannerm.com/vander.htm), if you are considering 1 mole of a substance, then the formula is

$$(P+a/V^2)(V-b) = RT$$

For $n$ moles

$$(P+an^2/V^2)(V-nb) = nRT$$

The Science HQ website [Van der waal’s equation](http://www.sciencehq.com/chemistry/van-der-waals-equation.html), the constants $a$ and $b$ represent pressure and volume corrections respectively.  The units are based on the formula for $n$ moles of substance (the 2nd equation above).

Taking each term on the left hand side individually:

$(P+an^2/V^2)$ is the van der Waals equation equivalent for $P$ in the ideal gas equation, thus this therm must have the same unit, so using $Pa$ as the unit for pressure would require that the units of $a$ to be $Pa L^2 mol^{-2}$  (the website uses the unit $atm$, but the same idea still applies.

In a similar manner, the term $(V-nb)$ is the van der Waals equivalent of $V$ in the ideal gas equation.  So to keep the unit as for volume in the second term, the unit for $b$ must be $Lmol^{-1}$.

One thing to always be careful with, as there are a number of units used for both pressure and volume, it is imperative to keep these constant throughout your calculations.

For example, volume can be expressed as $m^3$ or $L$ and several others (hence the $L^2$ term above would be the same as $(m^3)^2$ or simply $m^6$).

One final document is a master list of $a$ and $b$ constants for several chemicals (once again be careful with the units - unit conversion are provided in the document), [van der Waals constants for gases.](http://courses.chem.indiana.edu/c360/documents/vanderwaalsconstants.pdf). Also further explanations of the above can be found on this [Purdue University page entitled Deviations from Ideal Gas Law Behavior](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch4/deviation5.html)

Answer (score 6):

Since the van der Waals equation is derived from the ideal gas equation, the empirical constants $a$ and $b$ need to have dimensions so that the units work out.

The ideal gas constant $R$ has dimensions of $\dfrac{\text{pressure}\cdot\text{volume}}{\text{moles}\cdot\text{temperature}}$ since $R=\frac{pV}{nT}$ for an ideal gas. This is one of the definitions of $R$.

For the van der Waals equation, now $R=\dfrac{(p-\frac{a}{V^2})(V-b)}{nT}$

Since we have $(p-\frac{a}{V^2})$, the term $\frac{a}{V^2}$ needs to have units of pressure for this subtraction to not screw up the units.

$$\therefore \dfrac{a}{V^2}\equiv\text{pressure}\implies a\equiv \text{pressure}\cdot(\text{volume})^2$$

Now, we guarantee that $(p-\frac{a}{V^2})$ has units of pressure:

$$(p-\dfrac{a}{V^2}\equiv (\text{pressure}-\dfrac{\text{pressure}\cdot\text{volume}^2}{\text{volume}^2} \equiv \left(\text{pressure}-\text{pressure}\cdot \dfrac{\text{volume}^2}{\text{volume}^2} \right)\equiv (\text{pressure}-\text{pressure}) \equiv \text{pressure}$$

The constant $b$ is easier. $b$ needs to have dimensions of volume so that $V-b$ still has dimensions of volume.